# Stretch image grid out

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a small section of a page with a grid of images. I was wondering if there was a way so the images on the far left and right could always be stuck to the edge of the container, no matter the screen size.

I created the grid with flexbox by creating a grid of figures and making them inline and making the container, .grid, 75vw.

How can I do this? Here is the website: https://1080benchmarks.github.io/projects/portfolio/pages/webdesign.html

And here is the code

```
    .contentcontainer {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

    .content {
  width: 75vw;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
}

.grid {
  width: 75vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.gridimage {
  height: 220px;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry if I was a little bit confusing. So I have a grid of six items and I am trying to have it so the grid of images stretches to the edge of the container their in. I'm using flexbox and I could do it by changing margin, but that would mean I would need to use media queries for device sizes.